# Inserir data no bd com JDBC Google Script

Tags: google, data, script, jdbc

Estou tentando gravar no banco (MySQL) diversos dados, porém no dado do tipo data a execução da os seguinte erro:

> Não é possível encontrar método setTimestamp(number,string). (linha 32, arquivo "Código")

O código é:

```
var data = Utilities.formatDate(base.getRange(i,3).getValue(), "GMT-03:00", "dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
stmt.setTimestamp(3,data);
```

Não preciso gravar timestamp necessariamente, qualquer formato de data é o suficiente, porém esse formato foi o ultimo que tentei.

Answer (score 0):

Usei o seguinte para fazer a conversão:

```
var data = Jdbc.newTimestamp(base.getRange(i,3).getValue());
```